# help me to get each elements from my json feed ? Please 

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this JSON data:

```
 {
    "data":{
        "mat_149":{
            "id":"149",
            "title":"The closing of 40% profit within 9 month",
            "teaser":"profit within 9 months only which is equal to 52% annual profit",
            "body":" The auction was presented in a very high and commercial lands.\u000d\u000a",
            "files":{
                "911":{
                    "fid":"911",
                    "filename":"22.JPG",
                    "filepath":"http://mysite/files/22_0.JPG"
                }
            }
        },
        "mat_147":{
            "id":"147",
            "title":"Company launches the city ",
            "teaser":"demands for distinguished lands.",
            "body":" The area size is quare meters This is evident through projects and many other projects.\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a",
            "files":{
                "906":{
                    "fid":"906",
                    "filename":"2D7z.jpg",
                    "filepath":"http://mysite/dlr/files/2D7Z.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
        "mat_link":"mysite.com/"
    }
}
```

I'm parsing it like this with the json-framework:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:response error:nil];  
NSLog(@"Data : %@", [data valueForKey:@"data"] );
```

I am getting Data:

```
NSLog(@"Data : %@", [data objectForKey:@"data"] );
```

I am getting the data  , but what i should do to get the 'file' items like 'fid' , 'filename' , 'filepath' .How can i get each elements from 'Data' n 'files' and store into some NSStrings ........

Can someone point out what I have to do ? Please

Answer (score 0):

They're all sub-dictionaries aren't they,
just try logging the whole dictionary so go:

```
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Then you can see the structure.

To get all the other data, you're going to need to create a data model to hold it all, which knows which keys to call to get the specific strings.

Or you could call [data allKeys];
Iterating through that, getting dictionaries that you have the model object for.

E.g:

//Somewhere you declare this

```
NSArray *keys = [data allKeys]
for (NSString *key in [data allKeys]) {
NSDictionary *oneObject = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
MyObjectModel *object = [[MyObjectModel alloc] init];
object.id = [oneObject objectForKey:@"id"];
object.title = [oneObject objectForKey:@"title"];
//etc

//then you create another dict for files
}
```

Alex